# How to subscribe to YouTube user’s feed without Google account?

Tags: youtube, rss, feeds, rss-reader, google-news

How do I subscribe to a YouTube user’s feed (not playlists, likes, or comments) without a Google account?

E.g.:

```
https://www.youtube.com/user/$USERNAME/feed
```

I wish to have it in my normal feed reader. (not second source)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old question but new solutions exist now which allow you to make use of youtube without a google account.

**For phones** (android) - [NewPipe](https://newpipe.schabi.org/)
**For PCs** - [Ividious](https://github.com/iv-org/invidious), [Minitube](https://flavio.tordini.org/minitube), [FreeTube](https://freetubeapp.io)

Invidious can be self hosted or you can use a [public instance](https://instances.invidio.us/). Every channel has an RSS feed.

Both, NewPipe and Ividious can import your yt channel subscriptions. Youtube allows downloading the list as a file from [here](https://www.youtube.com/subscription_manager?action_takeout=1).

Answer (score 2):

You could try using [this Zapier Zap](https://zapier.com/z/CSl/zapbook/youtube/rss/6236/creates-an-rss-feed-of-a-users-youtube-feed/) which creates an RSS feed of any users YouTube video feed.

You just need to sub in the users YouTube username and [Zapier](https://zapier.com/z/7W/) will create the RSS feed you can put in your RSS feed.

[image: YouTube Users RSS Feed]

You can easily substitute the RSS feed in Zapier for other form of notification too like email, sms, instant message, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The URL for a user feed in YouTube is:

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/<user>/uploads
```

Replace  with the name of a YouTube channel or user.

[from: [Digital Inspiration](http://www.labnol.org/internet/rss-feeds-directory/21242/)]

Answer (score 0):

For the user's feed, use the following URL syntax:

> `https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?user=USER_ID`

For example: https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?user=Google

---

For the user's channel, use the following URL syntax:

> `https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=CHANGE_THIS`

For example: https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UC3x6qC4h-NyuvQBSZYaPKrQ

Answer (score -1):

Some feeds are not available via HTTPS, so if this doesn't work:

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/<user>/uploads
```

..then try HTTP (just remove the "s"):

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/<user>/uploads
```